# How to hide the first Item in ListBox WPF

Tags: .net, wpf, triggers

Hello fellow programmers!

Im trying to hide the first ListBoxItem inside my ListBox, what am i doing wrong? Im searching like crazy and cant get it to work. Would be a pleasure if someone could help :). ... But nothing gets hidden :(.

```
<ListBox x:Name="DemoItemsListBox" Margin="0 16 0 16" SelectedIndex="0" AlternationCount="2147483647"
     ItemsSource="{Binding NavItems}"
     PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp="UIElement_OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonUp"
          Cursor="Hand">

    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding (ItemsControl.AlternationIndex), RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListBoxItem}}" Value="0">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>

    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="domain:DemoItem">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="{Binding PackIconName}" Height="24" Width="24" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="32 0 32 0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

**Edit**
I got it **partially** working, the First Item is invisible, but i can still click on it and see it while hovering. Its also consuming space.

```
<ListBox x:Name="DemoItemsListBox" Margin="0 16 0 16" SelectedIndex="0" AlternationCount="2147483647"
     ItemsSource="{Binding NavItems}"
     PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp="UIElement_OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonUp"
          Cursor="Hand">

    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="domain:DemoItem">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Grid}">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding (ItemsControl.AlternationIndex), RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListBoxItem}}" Value="0">
                                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </Grid.Style>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="{Binding PackIconName}" Height="24" Width="24" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="32 0 32 0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

[image: Still visible ListBoxItem]

**Edit 2**
I got it working like this. How can i apply the Style with a Key? I tried like x:Key="MyCoolStyle" but i can't find where to place it.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="0">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"></Setter>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: is there any reason you cant just create a NavItemsFiltered property which is simply a getter which returns the NavItems greater than index 0? Seems alot simpler.

Comment: Oh yes, this would also help. Currently im kinda testing and thinking about my app. Maybe i will add something like "only users with right xy can view item xy". Maybe as a property or something like this. Or even just adding navitems which the user is able to see. My Intention was (because im new to wpf etc) to add a loginview, this is the First item in the list which should be hidden after the login. Im also new to the GUI framework im using. So i tried to get it working in any way. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Set the Visiblity to Collapsed to have not shown and not occupy the space.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried it with Collapsed, it didnt work, there was a smaller space, but still space left. I don't know how to post code here in comment. I tried it otherwise. Please have a look at Edit 2.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use like this,

```
    <ListBox x:Name="DemoItemsListBox" Margin="0 16 0 16" SelectedIndex="0" AlternationCount="2147483647"
                     ItemsSource="12345678"
                          Cursor="Hand">
        <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="0">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="domain:DemoItem">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Margin="32 0 32 0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

I have changed ItemsSource for my convenience..